# Do you capitalize the "T" in "the" in a Title or Place's Name?

Tags: grammar

When writing a title or a name of a place in a novel, do you capitalize the "T" in "the"?

For example the name of an establishment, which of these would be correct:

They went to **The** Cloak and Dagger Inn?

OR

They went to **the** Cloak and Dagger Inn?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You capitalize `The` if:

- It begins a sentence.
- It is part of the name.

So if the inn is `The Cloak and Dagger Inn`, everything is capitalized (except the `and` of course). If the name is the `Cloak and Dagger Inn`, then the `the` is not capitalized, as it is not part of the name.

On the other hand, if the `the` does not *start* the name, then it is not capitalized: `Inn of the Cloak and Dagger`.

Hopefully that wasn't too confusing. ;)

Comment: To clarify further, capitalize the T if it begins not only a sentence, but a title ("The Little Prince"). And even if "the" is part of a name but not at the beginning don't capitalize it ("King of the Hill").